# Scala Compiler 2.10.4 fails to compile HList model using Slick 2.0, but sometimes it works. Why?

Tags: scala, slick-2.0, play-slick

I get following compilation error using HList from Slick2.0. Most of the time I get this error, but sometimes I don't get this error. Also note that I am using Scala IDE 3.0.3 and I do not get any compliation error in Eclipse ( which is strange ). I even tried to close all the JVM processes before running `sbt clean compile`, still I get same compilation error, although intermittently:

```
$ sbt clean compile
[info] Resolving org.scoverage#scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.10;0.99.5 ...
[info] Done updating.
[error] ...../app/models/example/Up.scala:77: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Option[scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Long,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Option[java.sql.Timestamp],scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HCons[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HNil.type]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
[error]  required: Option[scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Long,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Option[java.sql.Timestamp],scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.syntax.::[Boolean,scala.slick.collection.heterogenous.HNil.type]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
[error]            Up.unapply _
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 20 s, completed 31 Oct, 2014 9:20:31 PM
```

The file in question `app/models/example/Up.scala` is as shown below:

```
package models.example

import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.Tag
import scala.slick.collection.heterogenous._
import java.sql.Timestamp


class Up(
  val id: Long, val createdDate: Option[Timestamp], val c2: Boolean,
  val c3: Boolean, val c4: Boolean, val c5: Boolean, val c6: Boolean,
  val c7: Boolean, val c8: Boolean, val c9: Boolean, val c10: Boolean,
  val c11: Boolean, val c12: Boolean, val c13: Boolean, val c14: Boolean,
  val c15: Boolean, val c16: Boolean, val c17: Boolean, val c18: Boolean,
  val c19: Boolean, val c20: Boolean, val c21: Boolean, val c22: Boolean,
  val c23: Boolean, val c24: Boolean, val c25: Boolean, val c26: Boolean,
  val c27: Boolean, val c28: Boolean, val c29: Boolean, val c30: Boolean,
  val c31: Boolean, val c32: Boolean, val c33: Boolean, val c34: Boolean,
  val c35: Boolean, val c36: Boolean, val c37: Boolean, val c38: Boolean,
  val c39: Boolean, val c40: Boolean, val c41: Boolean, val c42: Boolean,
  val c43: Boolean, val c44: Boolean, val c45: Boolean, val c46: Boolean)

object Up {
  def apply(
    id: Long, createdDate: Option[Timestamp],
    c2: Boolean, c3: Boolean, c4: Boolean, c5: Boolean,
    c6: Boolean, c7: Boolean, c8: Boolean, c9: Boolean, c10: Boolean,
    c11: Boolean, c12: Boolean, c13: Boolean, c14: Boolean, c15: Boolean,
    c16: Boolean, c17: Boolean, c18: Boolean, c19: Boolean, c20: Boolean,
    c21: Boolean, c22: Boolean, c23: Boolean, c24: Boolean, c25: Boolean,
    c26: Boolean, c27: Boolean, c28: Boolean, c29: Boolean, c30: Boolean,
    c31: Boolean, c32: Boolean, c33: Boolean, c34: Boolean, c35: Boolean,
    c36: Boolean, c37: Boolean, c38: Boolean, c39: Boolean, c40: Boolean,
    c41: Boolean, c42: Boolean, c43: Boolean, c44: Boolean, c45: Boolean,
    c46: Boolean
  ) = new Up(
    id, createdDate,
    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12,
    c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19, c20, c21, c22, c23,
    c24, c25, c26, c27, c28, c29, c30, c31, c32, c33, c34,
    c35, c36, c37, c38, c39, c40, c41, c42, c43, c44, c45,
    c46
  )

  def unapply(x: Up) = {
    val data = x.id ::
    x.createdDate ::
    x.c2 :: x.c3 :: x.c4 :: x.c5 :: x.c6 :: x.c7 :: x.c8 :: x.c9 :: x.c10 ::
    x.c11 :: x.c12 :: x.c13 :: x.c14 :: x.c15 :: x.c16 :: x.c17 :: x.c18 :: x.c19 ::
    x.c20 :: x.c21 :: x.c22 :: x.c23 :: x.c24 :: x.c25 :: x.c26 :: x.c27 :: x.c28 ::
    x.c29 :: x.c30 :: x.c31 :: x.c32 :: x.c33 :: x.c34 :: x.c35 :: x.c36 :: x.c37 ::
    x.c38 :: x.c39 :: x.c40 :: x.c41 :: x.c42 :: x.c43 :: x.c44 :: x.c45 :: x.c46 ::
     HNil

     Option[data.type](data)
   }
 }

 class Ups(tag: Tag) extends Table[Up](tag, "ups") {
   def * = (
     id :: createdDate ::
       c2 :: c3 :: c4 :: c5 :: c6 :: c7 :: c8 :: c9 :: c10 :: c11 :: c12 :: c13 ::
       c14 :: c15 :: c16 :: c17 :: c18 :: c19 :: c20 :: c21 :: c22 :: c23 :: c24 ::
       c25 :: c26 :: c27 :: c28 :: c29 :: c30 :: c31 :: c32 :: c33 :: c34 :: c35 ::
       c36 :: c37 :: c38 :: c39 :: c40 :: c41 :: c42 :: c43 :: c44 :: c45 :: c46 ::
       HNil).shaped <> (
     {
       case x => Up(
         x(0), x(1), x(2),
         x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8), x(9), x(10), x(11), x(12), x(13),
         x(14), x(15), x(16), x(17), x(18), x(19), x(20), x(21), x(22), x(23), x(24),
         x(25), x(26), x(27), x(28), x(29), x(30), x(31), x(32), x(33), x(34), x(35),
         x(36), x(37), x(38), x(39), x(40), x(41), x(42), x(43), x(44), x(45), x(46)
       )
     },
         {
           Up.unapply _
         })

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.NotNull)
  def createdDate = column[Option[Timestamp]]("created_date")
  def c2 = column[Boolean]("c2")
  def c3 = column[Boolean]("c3")
  def c4 = column[Boolean]("c4")
  def c5 = column[Boolean]("c5")
  def c6 = column[Boolean]("c6")
  def c7 = column[Boolean]("c7")
  def c8 = column[Boolean]("c8")
  def c9 = column[Boolean]("c9")
  def c10 = column[Boolean]("c10")
  def c11 = column[Boolean]("c11")
  def c12 = column[Boolean]("c12")
  def c13 = column[Boolean]("c13")
  def c14 = column[Boolean]("c14")
  def c15 = column[Boolean]("c15")
  def c16 = column[Boolean]("c16")
  def c17 = column[Boolean]("c17")
  def c18 = column[Boolean]("c18")
  def c19 = column[Boolean]("c19")
  def c20 = column[Boolean]("c20")
  def c21 = column[Boolean]("c21")
  def c22 = column[Boolean]("c22")
  def c23 = column[Boolean]("c23")
  def c24 = column[Boolean]("c24")
  def c25 = column[Boolean]("c25")
  def c26 = column[Boolean]("c26")
  def c27 = column[Boolean]("c27")
  def c28 = column[Boolean]("c28")
  def c29 = column[Boolean]("c29")
  def c30 = column[Boolean]("c30")
  def c31 = column[Boolean]("c31")
  def c32 = column[Boolean]("c32")
  def c33 = column[Boolean]("c33")
  def c34 = column[Boolean]("c34")
  def c35 = column[Boolean]("c35")
  def c36 = column[Boolean]("c36")
  def c37 = column[Boolean]("c37")
  def c38 = column[Boolean]("c38")
  def c39 = column[Boolean]("c39")
  def c40 = column[Boolean]("c40")
  def c41 = column[Boolean]("c41")
  def c42 = column[Boolean]("c42")
  def c43 = column[Boolean]("c43")
  def c44 = column[Boolean]("c44")
  def c45 = column[Boolean]("c45")
  def c46 = column[Boolean]("c46")
}

object Ups {
  val ups = TableQuery[Ups]
  def get(id: Long)(implicit session: Session): Option[Up] = {ups.where(_.id === id).firstOption}
}
```

I thought it could be because of a bug in Scala Compiler - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8146

So I upgraded to Scala 2.10.4 but still I receive compilation errors.

Contents of `build.sbt`:

```
name := "play-sample"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1",
  "com.nulab-inc" %% "play2-oauth2-provider" % "0.7.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings

instrumentSettings
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I used HList in that project and I realized that it was caused by the compilation process running in Eclipse that was "colliding" with the compilation issued by SBT.

Just try to close Eclipse and compile your project via SBT and see what happens.

I've tried compiling your project on Scala 2.10.4 and Scala 2.11.2 and I had no problems. If you add your 'build.sbt', a look to your 'libraryDependencies' may be helpful.

Comment: I have metioned in question that I tried it will closing all JVM processes, including Eclipse. Still I sometimes see this compliation error. Also I just added the `build.sbt` file. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I tried to compile against play-slick 0.8.0 that uses slick 2.1.x. I don't know if you are bounded for a specific reason to 0.6.1. Try to fork your project and upgrade to a more recent version ad see what happens. You'll be required to upgrade play too.

Comment: I found the solution. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this problem [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/214) so just for the record I found the solution.

I had to override the play settings and set Scala-2.10.4 as the compiler. This is how the `build.sbt` looks now:

```
play.Project.playScalaSettings

name := "play-sample"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1",
  "com.nulab-inc" %% "play2-oauth2-provider" % "0.7.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2"
)

instrumentSettings
```

It showed to me scala version 2.10.3

```
[play-sample] $ scalaVersion
[info] 2.10.3
```

Then I updated `build.sbt`

```
[play-sample] $ scalaVersion
[info] 2.10.4
```

And now it compiles just fine, without any errors.